# Laravel - Query with eager loading and left join -> sub-object empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, left-join, eloquent, eager-loading

### I have those four tables:

```
    1. objects           2. objectdates       3. objectphotos        4. imagefiles
+------------------+  +------------------+  +------------------+  +------------------+
| columns          |  | columns          |  | columns          |  | columns          |
+------------------+  +------------------+  +------------------+  +------------------+
| id               |  | id               |  | id               |  | id               |
| title            |  | object_id        |  | object_id        |  |                  |
|                  |  |                  |  | imagefile_id     |  |                  |
+------------------+  +------------------+  +------------------+  +------------------+
```

### The query I am using:

```
$objects = Object::with(array(
    'objectdate' => function($query){
        $query->select('id', 'id AS objectdate_id', 'object_id');
    }
))
->select(
    'objects.id', 'objects.id AS object_id', 'objects.title',
    'objectphotos.id AS objectphoto_id',
    'imagefiles.id', 'imagefiles.id AS imagefile_id'
)
->leftJoin('objectphotos', 'objects.id', '=', 'objectphotos.object_id')
->leftJoin('imagefiles', 'imagefiles.id', '=', 'objectphotos.imagefile_id')
->groupBy('objects.id')->get();
```

MySQL output result:

```
select `objects`.`id`, `objects`.`id` as `object_id`, `objects`.`title`, 
`objectphotos`.`id` as `objectphoto_id`, `imagefiles`.`id`, 
`imagefiles`.`id` as `imagefile_id` from `objects` 
left join `objectphotos` on `objects`.`id` = `objectphotos`.`object_id` 
left join `imagefiles` on `imagefiles`.`id` = `objectphotos`.`imagefile_id` 
where `objects`.`deleted_at` is null group by `objects`.`id`


select `id`, `id` as `objectdate_id`, `object_id` from `objectdates` where `objectdates`.`object_id` 
in ('29', '36', '46', '57', '71', '91', '107', '115', '129', '141', '152', '154') order by
`objectdates`.`date` asc, `objectdates`.`timeofday` asc
```

### Relations:

- Object->hasMany('Objectdate')
- Object->hasMany('objectphoto')
- Objectphoto->belongsTo('Imagefile')
- (Imagefile doesn't belongsTo Objectphoto because contain images that are not Objectphoto)

### My problem:

When I use the query above, my objectdate object is empty:

```
["objectdate"]=>
    object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1018 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
```

And when I remove 'imagefiles' from the query, everything is working as expected, I get all the dates in my object objectdate:

```
$objects = Object::with(array(
    'objectdate' => function($query){
        $query->select('id', 'id AS objectdate_id', 'object_id');
    }
))
->select(
    'objects.id', 'objects.id AS object_id', 'objects.title',
    'objectphotos.id AS objectphoto_id'
)
->leftJoin('objectphotos', 'objects.id', '=', 'objectphotos.object_id')
->groupBy('objects.id')->get();
```

The thing is that this issue is specific to this the object objectdates. I have another table called users and the object is working perfectly with imagefiles in eager loading ...

**Why my object is empty in the first case?** 
I'd like to keep 1 query for that because laravel output is perfect

*If this is not possible to keep one query, how can I add objectdates in my main object ? Because I'm using objectdates to sort the results.*

All help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?